# JavaScript rounding numbers

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I know that I can round a number like this

```
var number = 1.3;
Math.round(number);
```

and the result I'm given is `1`.

But how can I round a number to the next highest whole number? So round `1.3` to `2` instead of `1`?

Comment: also note that `Math.round` doesn't round _down_, it rounds to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var rounded = Math.ceil(number);
```

As an aside, in platforms with no `ceil` method available, and assuming `round` rounds to the nearest integer, a common trick used to round upwards is:

```
var rounded = Math.round(number + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `Math.ceil()` instead.  It rounds the number up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [**Math.floor(number)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)!

Although, I would recommend against using javascript to do arithmetic... I don't know the exact reasons (but i just asked a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501307/common-pitfalls-with-javascripts-math-object) =P).